# How to convert string containing "+=��@0���o2E" to short array?

Tags: java, string, hex, byte, short

I am sending hex values from `Arduino` to Android over `Uart`. I am storing the received bytes from `byte[]` buffer to a long string in Android side. And, after storing in string I want to convert it to the hex or I want my array to support values above than 128.

when I am doing this

```
byte[] received_byte= string.getBytes();
String received = bytesToHex(received_array);

static String bytesToHex(byte[] hashInBytes) {
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : hashInBytes) {
        value.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
    }
    return value.toString();
}
```

`Arduino` is sending this: `2b18021a00011a1a0708403081806f0132140845`

received string contains this: `2b18021a00011a1a07084030efbfbdefbfbdefbfbd6f0132140845`

I know bytes does not support values above than 128. I even tried to change the received_byte in `short []` but problem with that is my string contains this `"+=��@0���o2E"`  since I am directly storing the data directly from the `byte[]` buffer.

Please let me know if I am not clear in my question.

Comment: You shouldn't convert the byte buffer to a string to begin with if it doesn't contain character data.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean by things like "long string", but you may want a `ByteBuffer`, which is intended to allow you to write a byte stream and then read multibyte values interpreted as different data types (such as an `int` or `long`).

Comment: @chrylis Could you Please tell me how to use ByteBuffer and how that will help me out?

Comment: He has already told you how it will help you out, and how to use it is right there in the Javadoc.

Comment: @chrylis So what I did  I wrapped my String to ByteBuffer and stored the value in int. If send 80 in hex from Arduino it shows -17ffff. 
I am doing something wrong here?